# RandomForestClassifier differ from BaggingClassifier

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest

How is using a `BaggingClassifier` with `baseestimator=RandomForestClassifier` differ from a `RandomForestClassifier` in `sklearn`?

Comment: I think you mean `BaggingClassifier` with `base_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier` right?

Comment: with base_estimator=RandomForestClassifer(), cant we use it?

Comment: You can but then I don't see the point.

Answer (score 5):

The `RandomForestClassifier` introduces randomness externally (relative to the individual tree fitting) via bagging as `BaggingClassifier` does.

However it injects randomness also deep inside the tree construction procedure by sub-sampling the list of features that are candidate for splitting: a new random set of features is considered at each new split. This randomness is controlled via the `max_features` parameter of `RandomForestClassifier` that has no equivalent in `BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier())`.

Comment: but BaggingClassifier also has the parameter max_features?how does it differ then?
for n_estimators=500 BaggingClassifier doesnt work but in RandomForestClassifier it does so i was wondering what causes such a big time and memory difference in the two cases.

Comment: The feature sampling of BaggingClassifier is doing one feature sampling operation per tree. The features sampling of `RandomForestClassifier` is doing one independent feature sampling **per split / node** in the trees.

Comment: Thank You, clears few doubts, its a big field to explore and understand! :)